# How to detect the session timeout in Asp.net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can see how to put stuff in Session and Cache from [this project](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching).

Can you please tell me how to detect the session timeout in controllers/actions? Do we need some kind of attribute for it?

Comment: Yes, Create an attribute and keep it as attribute for the controller/action and in the attribute class check session value and if not valid redirect to login page

Comment: I don't want to check my own objects in the session whether they exist or not. I need a global strategy to see if old session is expired?

Comment: Session expiration is only tracked via its IDistributedCache entry expiration, which has no notification mechanic. What are you trying to do when the session expires?

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would try to use MVC6 cache tag helper.

Here you can read more
http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/03/mvc-6-cache-tag-helper.aspx